# Modular representation symmetric group

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory

We know that if the characteristic of a field $F$ divides $|G|,$ then $FG$ is semisimple and in this case, the decomposition of $FG$ is obtained by using the Wedderburn-Artin theorem.

I wanted to learn about the modular case. For example, I am curious to know about the description of the structure of $F_2S_n,$ or at least of $F_2S_5$ to start with. Any reference suggestion would be of great help. Thanks!

Comment: James's Representations of Symmetric Groups is the standard text for modular representations of symmetric groups.

Comment: Ok. Thanks alot